# Actionscript using \Q to ignore specials. Getting strange results

Tags: regex, actionscript

thanks for reading my question.

I am using a RegExp object in actionscript to simply test the occurrence of one string inside another.  Sometimes the Strings may contain RegEx special characters, i.e. "*".

To handle that I have been concatenating \Q to the beginning of the search string, like so...

```
(String(reportItem[attributeToSearch])).search(new RegExp(("\Q" + searchText), "i"))
```

That is currently working for larger strings and for the string "`*`".
However, I've come across a problem where the String I am searching is "projectiles, with bursting charge".  I am search for ",s" and it gives me back -1 as a result.  If I search the same thing without the \Q it works fine, but then the "`*`" case breaks.

What gives?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You also need to escape the `\` in the `\Q` `new RegExp(("\\Q" + searchText)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` in the `\Q`

```
new RegExp(("\\Q" + searchText), "i");
```

Try this:

```
var regExp:RegExp;
regExp = new RegExp("\Qs,", "i");
trace(regExp.toString()); //    /Qs,/i

regExp = /\Qs,/i;               
trace(regExp.toString()); //    /\Qs,/i

regExp = new RegExp("\\Qs,", "i");
trace(regExp.toString()); //    /\Qs,/i
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

<del>You could escape any special characters in the user's search before including it in the regex using the code below. Unfortunately flex doesn't have any built-in way to escape a regex string.</del>

```
private function escapeRegex(s:String):String {
   var result:String = s.replace(
      new RegExp("([{}\(\)\^$&.\*\?\/\+\|\[\\\\]|\]|\-)","g"), "\\$1");
   return result;
}
```

<del>(Thanks to http://www.flexer.info/2008/08/07/how-to-escape-all-regexp-special-chars/ )</del>

You might also consider just using a regular search and `toLowerCase` if you don't need to take advantage of any regex facilities.

**EDIT:** As Jacob pointed out, \Q does indeed work and that's a better solution than escaping it manually.

Comment: -1 for escaping special characters manually. +1 for recommending a regular search. net 0